# How to remove event emitter from particular function node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, events

I have an common event emitter.

```
var events = require('events');
var eventEmitter = new events.EventEmitter();
```

which emites events like pause, resume , cancel.

i listen to this events in my function. but this functions are called inside for loop.

```
let func = () =>{
   //some Action runs async;
   eventEmitter.on("pause",()=>{
     //some action;
   });
   eventEmitter.on("resume",()=>{
     //some action;
   }) 
  eventEmitter.on("cancel",()=>{
     //some action;
   }) 
  return 0;
}

for(let i=0;i<anyNumber;i++){
   func();
}
```

**EDIT :** my real indention is to read files in a directory recursively and upload to s3 Bucket, since there is no official method to upload a whole directory, i achieved through this.

The for loop mentioned above is actually a fs.readdir, for sake of simplicity i mentioned it as for loop.

in func() i have the s3 upload function (multipart upload) while pause button clicked i need to pause the upload  (which means leave current part uploading already, and stop another part to be uploaded.)

while resume means part upload continues, while cancel means i cancel the multipart upload.

this is my exact case.

```
const readdirp = require('readdirp');
readdirp('.', {fileFilter: '*.js', alwaysStat: true})
 .on('data', (entry) => {
  const {path, stats: {size}} = entry;
  s3Fileupload(path)
})
.on('warn', error => console.error('non-fatal error', error))
.on('error', error => console.error('fatal error', error))
.on('end', () => console.log('done'));
```

can you now help me out ?

***EDIT:1***

```
let func = () =>{
 let stream = es.map((data, next) => {
  queue.defer(function(details, done) {
    _this.s3MultiUpload(JSON.parse(details), options, done, details, next);
  }, data);
}); }
let stream = readdirp(path)
stream.pipe(this.func());
```

may be the d3Queue i am using here may causing memory leak, i am pushing the function all the way when reading directory ?

Comment: Most likely you do not need to call func() in a loop. You only need to attach each event listeners once. They will be called for every event in the future.

Comment: @Dafang Can you explain, I need this func()  executed that much time. Explain in detail please

Comment: We need to see greater context in your code to understand how these event emitters are used to know exactly what to suggest.   It's unlikely you want to add event listeners in a loop in the first place as it does you little use to have multiple copies of the exact same event listener on the same emitter.  So, to know what to suggest we need to see the overall problem you're actually trying to solve with these listeners.  What you are literally asking for is probably not the right solution to your actual problem.  You need a better design that doesn't have this problem.

Comment: If you call `on("cancel", ...)` 10 times, you are saying every time the event "cancel" is fired, run this function 10 times. 10 events will trigger 100 function calls. It's a common mistake where people actually want to call the function once for the next 10 events. We can answer the question better if you clarify your intention.

Comment: @DafangCao i updated my question with my indention can you help me

Comment: @jfriend00 i updated my question, what i am really doing

Comment: Please show the actual code that's using `fs.readdir()`.  There is certainly a better way to code this than what you are trying.

Comment: @jfriend00 i updated my code

Comment: @DafangCao i updated my edit, i think this may cause memory leak !

Comment: @jfriend00  i updated my edit, i think this may cause memory leak !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To remove a listener, call `eventEmitter.removeListener(event, listener)`.
You need to keep a copy of all listeners attached around.
Alternatively you can simply call `eventEmitter.removeAllListeners()` if the emitter is not used elsewhere.

> If I do this, I can't listen to that event after that right?

You are right. You need to **wait** till you no longer need the events, then remove them.

Ideally, you do not want to attach too many listeners.
Instead of increasing the limit, do all the work in a single event callback.

Here is how I would do it:

```
// Create an event emitter
const events = require('events');
const eventEmitter = new events.EventEmitter();

// Build a list of tasks to run
let tasks = [];
let tasksDone = 0;
for (let file of files) {
    // Each task can be paused, resumed, canceled
    let task = tasks.push({
        pause: () => {/* TODO */},
        resume: () => {/* TODO */},
        cancel: () => {/* TODO */},
        start: async () => {
            // Do work
            // Send a signal when task is done
            eventEmitter.emit('done');
        }
    });
    tasks.push(task);
}

// Store the listeners
let listeners = [
    ['pause', () => {
        tasks.forEach(task => task.pause());
    }],
    ['resume', () => {
        tasks.forEach(task => task.resume());
    }],
    ['cancel', () => {
        tasks.forEach(task => task.cancel());
    }],
    ['done', () => {
        tasksDone++;
        if (tasksDone === task.length) {
            // All work done
            // Remove listeners
            listeners.forEach(([event, callback]) => {
                eventEmitter.removeListener(event, callback);
            });
        }
    }],
];

// Attach listeners
listeners.forEach(([event, callback]) => {
    eventEmitter.on(event, callback);
});

// Start tasks
tasks.forEach(task => task.start());
```

With all that said, your application may be crashing for other reasons.
If you open too many files at the same time, or use too much memory, your application can crash before the tasks are done. Goes without saying you should also make sure that the files are closed etc.

I would recommend start by doing queuing the tasks and doing them one at a time.
If you need more throughput, write a scheduler to make sure you don't consume too much resource at a time.

Lastly, for a node program, you can attach Chrome debugger to find out why memory is not freed. You can find out exactly what is holding onto memory if the issue persists.

Comment: I taken heap snapshot, it increasing every time, upto 130MB, and closure is on top having more object Count and shallow size. how to reduce this.

Comment: `(closure)` is created when a function accesses variables outside its body. It's expected for them to have a high object count and shallow size. 130MB is not too outrageous, YouTube for example has a 160MB heap snapshot. It's difficult to trouble shoot memory leaks without knowledge of your system. Try read up a tutorial on [memory problems](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/memory-problems/#identify_js_heap_memory_leaks_with_allocation_timelines).